# How can I keep an output stream open in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, stream

I am writing data to a stream inside event:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```

As follows (taken from Apple's documentation):

```
case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
    uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *)[self.outData mutableBytes];            
    readBytes += byteIndex;            
    int dataLength = [self.outData length];            
    unsigned int length = ((dataLength - byteIndex >= 1024) ? 1024 : (dataLength - byteIndex));            
    uint8_t buffer[length];            
    (void)memcpy(buffer, readBytes, length);            
    length = [self.outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:length];            
    byteIndex += length;            
    break;
```

However, the event `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` is called when there is nothing else to write in the output stream, so the output stream is discarded. How can I keep this stream open for writing? According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html) this event is called correctly because nothing is written to the output stream. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you put your streams in a runloop?
See the example here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: Workshed's example is awesome and one I am currently following, but there is a bug there in that NSStreamEventEndEncountered is never caught in the case statement.  HOWEVER, if you replace NSStreamEventEndEncountered with its typedef of 4, it is caught and the sample stops working.  Though this example from Ceasar is great, it appears that there are two bugs in the handleEvent method that allow it to work.  Fixing either of them breaks the sample.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't clear on this point, but a reasonable interpretation is that the stream will send `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` when you have written up to its capacity. (The unclear part is whether this is true of all streams or only those [where you specify a capacity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOutputStream/outputStreamToBuffer%3acapacity%3a). A file-based stream, for example, could send `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` when the volume that the file is on is full.)

Given that the definition of a “capacity” is that you cannot write more than that much, keeping the stream open past that point doesn't make sense. Even if you have more bytes to write, the stream has no place to put them.